# grouping events in a time series with R

Tags: r, time-series

I've been doing some logging to try and illustrate to Comcast Business the frequency of their service interruptions at my office. I'm logging ping response times to a file then parsing that file with R. In the log file a value of 1000 means the ping timed out. My script logs the pings every 5 seconds. So if my Comcast service is down for 30 seconds that would result in ~6 log entries with value of 1000. I'd like to parse my logs in such a way that I could create a summary table that showed when each outage started, and how long it lasted. What are some good ways to do this?

Here's some example data from today and some graphs that illustrate my time series:

```
require(xts)
outFile <- "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SJuMQ9rD"
pingLog <- read.csv(outFile, header=FALSE, 
     col.names = c("time","ms"), 
     colClasses=c("POSIXct", "numeric"))
xPingLog <- as.xts(pingLog$ms, order.by=pingLog$time)
outages <- subset(pingLog, ms==1000)
xOutages <- as.xts(outages$ms, order.by=outages$time)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(xPingLog)
plot(outages)
outages
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got to love Run length encoding, alias `rle`:

```
offline <- ifelse(pingLog$ms==1000, TRUE, FALSE)
rleOffline <- rle(offline)

offlineTable <- data.frame(
    endtime = pingLog$time[cumsum(rleOffline$lengths)],
    duration = rleOffline$lengths * 5,
    offline = rleOffline$values
)
```

Results in:

```
offlineTable

              endtime duration offline
1 2011-11-20 13:20:19     1030   FALSE
2 2011-11-20 13:20:35        5    TRUE
3 2011-11-20 13:24:37      240   FALSE
4 2011-11-20 13:25:57       25    TRUE
5 2011-11-20 13:53:28     1640   FALSE
```

---

### Why does this work?

First construct a logical vector that indicates online vs. offline.  `ifelse` is handy for this.

```
offline <- ifelse(pingLog$ms==1000, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Then use `rle` to calculate the run length encoding:

```
rle(offline)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 206 1 48 5 328
  values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

This table tells how how many runs of either TRUE or FALSE occurred, and also how long each run was.  In this case, the first run was 206 periods with a value of FALSE (i.e. online for 206*5=1030 seconds.

The final step is to use the `rle` information to index against the original `pingLog` to find the times.  The extra bit of magic is to use `cumsum` to calculate the cumulative sum of the run-lengths.  The real-world meaning of this is the index position where each run terminated.

Comment: ... that's one handy function!

Comment: Awesome! That's a new function to me too.

Comment: `ifelse(pingLog$ms==1000, TRUE, FALSE)` could be shortened to `pingLog$ms==1000`